# Android dynamic modification of list

Tags: android, listview

I created a modified ListView, in order to display various information on the screen. Now I want to perform an individual action on the View the user has clicked, like making it invisible.

I tried something, but it doesn't seem to work properly. It makes each of the 4 views invisible, instead of just 1.

```
public class affichageListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public void actionC(){
        ListListView.get(0).test();
    } 
// some more code ...
}

public class affichageListView extends LinearLayout {
    // some more code ...
    public void test(){
         textViewTest.setVisibility(GONE);
    } 
}


public class listeVideo extends ListFragment{
    private affichageListViewAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        adapter.test();
    }
}

public class affichageListView extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView mTextView;

    public affichageListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public affichageListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public affichageListView(Context context) {
         super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.affichafe_list_view, this);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitre);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purpose you should have an array element of boolean in your adapter, with every. Then, add this method in your adapter:

```
public void hideItem(int position){
    positionsToShow.get(position) = false;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void showItem(int position){
    positionsToShow.get(position) = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in your getView you should put:

```
if(!positionsToShow.get(position)){
    //textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```